# CICS Explorer- DB2 connectivity

Tags: osgi, cics

I am developing a simple java program in CICS Explorer to connect to DB2 on mainframe.
Using the plug-in development option in CICS Explorer, I have converted the DB2 jars as plug-ins,deployed them and added the deployed plugins in the JVM profile OSGi Bundles option .I have also added the same in the LIBPATH  option in JVMProfile and in the CICS Explorer target platform.

But on deploying the bundle in CICS , I am getting the error :

**Error msg     : No Suitable driver
SQLSTATE      : 08001
Error code    : 0**

Kindly help me trace the issue

Answer (score 3):

If you're having to convert the DB2 JARs into OSGi bundles it's likely that you've not got the requisite APARs applied. If you use the JARs that are provided with the following APARs:

[PM36832](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PM36832)
[PM36838](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PM36838)

then they are already OSGi bundles, *plus*, they also register the DB2 Driver automatically - avoiding the 'No Suitable driver' problem.